# template static var = undefined reference

Tags: c++

This code runs fine in MSVC but according to gcc-4.7.2 C++11 the linker gets the problems below. Whats wrong with it

[Demo](http://ideone.com/uJiCw0)

Error:

```
/home/r7Qecv/ccEZjv1w.o: In function `main':
prog.cpp:(.text.startup+0xa): undefined reference to `Foo<long>::s'
prog.cpp:(.text.startup+0x17): undefined reference to `Foo<int>::s'
prog.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2c): undefined reference to `Foo<long>::s'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Foo{
public:
    T a;
    static T s;
};
template<>
int Foo<int>::s;
template<>
long Foo<long>::s;
int main(){

    Foo<int> f;
    Foo<long> f2;
    f.a=4;
    f.s=6;
    f2.a=8;
    std::cout<<f2.s;
    f2.s=11;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it's odd to refer to the static using an instance (`f.s`), but changing that doesn't make it compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't instantiated your static members, you only declared them.

Do this (or similar):

```
template<>
int Foo<int>::s = 0;
template<>
long Foo<long>::s = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer is, you need to initialize the static members for it to be a definition:

14.7.3p13

> An explicit specialization of a static data member of a template is a
>   definition if the declaration includes an initializer; otherwise, it
>   is a declaration.